# Parse Phone based login in Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, parse-platform

I am developing Cordova application using parse. For now I am using Email based authentication for login and recently I found [phone-based login](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/phone-based-login-can-you-dig-it/) blog on parse for android and iOS. Can we use that process for login in Cordova application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it would work just fine in a mobile-web based application.  In the GitHub repository ( https://github.com/parseplatform/anyphone ) there is already a web based version, and all the setup instructions are there.

The basic path is that you call a cloud-function with the phone number, which sends the text.  Then you call the cloud function with the phone number and the code they entered.  This validates and returns a user session token, which the client can use the `become` method on Parse.User to set the current user.